# create an array and loop through displaying each in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays, loops

id like to create an array storing:

```
document title
document summary
document link
```

and then loop through each entry, displaying each in the html.

so far ive got my array..:

```
var docs = [
{
    doc-title: "onesider number 1",
    doc-info:    "its onesider number 1",
    doc-src: "link here"
},

{
    doc-title: "Onesider number 2",
    doc-info:    "its onesider number 2",
    doc-src: "link here"
}

];
```

but after this I have no idea how to loop and display each. any suggestions?

Comment: These are not valid objects literals, if you intend to use hyphens in your keys, double quote them : `"doc-title": "onesider number 1"` and then retrieve the values like this : `doc["doc-title"]` instead of `doc.doc-title` which will not work. In my opinion, you should avoid using hyphens, unless you have no choice, use camel case instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two questions at a time:

- how to **loop** in javascript
- how to **append data** *—from that loop—* to the DOM

You can check this question about [loops in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript), the [each() function in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/), also take a look at append, prepend, text, html, attr functions in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Here is probably what you are trying to achieve (assuming you are using jQuery) :

```
var docs = [
    {
        docTitle: "onesider number 1",
        docInfo:    "its onesider number 1",
        docSrc: "link here"
    },
    {
        docTitle: "Onesider number 2",
        docInfo:    "its onesider number 2",
        docSrc: "link here"
    }
],

// This should be your items container  
container = $('#documents');


$.each(docs,function(i,doc){

    // Let's create the DOM
    var item = $('<div>').addClass('item'),
        title = $('<h1>'),
        info = $('<p>'),
        link = $('<a>');

    // Add content to the DOM
    link.attr('href',doc.docSrc)
    .text(doc.docTitle)
    .appendTo(title);

    info.text(doc.docInfo);

    // Append the infos to the item
    item.append(title,info);

    // Append the item to the container
    item.appendTo(container);
});
```

With this base html :

```
<div id="documents"></div>
```

you should end-up with something like :

```
<div id="documents">
  <div class="item">
    <h1><a href="link here">onesider number 1</a></h1>
    <p>its onesider number 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h1><a href="link here">onesider number 2</a></h1>
    <p>its onesider number 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [the working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RJuHE/)

Comment: thank you - both answers were right but this gave me everything i needed

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.each` to loop all items.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$.each(docs, function(index, obj){
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        alert(key+'=='+value); //manipulate the items here
    })  
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WypxX/1/

Comment: Bravo. Your answer is the first I've seen that shows that two loops are required to loop through an array of objects. Makes sense when I see it, but I could not figure it out. Thanks!